# Pydantic: Iterate over all instances of an class

Tags: python, pydantic

I want to iterate over all existing instances of a class (server) in pydantic:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from typing import List, Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.schema import schema

class Share(BaseModel):
    exportstring: str
    mountpoint: str
    options: str

class Server(BaseModel):
    srvname: str
    shares: List[Share]

class ServerList(BaseModel):
    __root__: List[Server]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.__root__)

    def __getitem__(self, Server):
        return self.__root__[Server]

srv1 = Server(srvname="horst1", shares=[Share(exportstring='export1server:/vol/asdfasdf', mountpoint='/opt/bla', options='nfsvers=4,rw,sync'), Share(exportstring='export1server:/vol/blub', mountpoint='/opt/bluba', options='nfsvers=4,rw,sync')])

srv1 = Server(srvname="harry", shares=[Share(exportstring='export1server:/vol/asdfasdf', mountpoint='/opt/bla', options='nfsvers=4,rw,sync'), Share(exportstring='export1server:/vol/blub', mountpoint='/opt/bluba', options='nfsvers=4,rw,sync')])
```

I tried to use this kind of metaclass Serverliste but without success...

Something like this doesn't work:

```py
for item in ServerList:
    print(item)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What if you have a list, and every time a object of that class is created, add the object to the list?

Comment: It's generally better to maintain an explicit list of instances of interest, rather than making the class keep track of *all* instances.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by writing your own `__init__`, calling the super's `__init__` registering the instance to some registry (a list here) and then iterating the registry.

The trick isn't in the `__init__` plumbing.  The trick is that pydantic class creation mechanism (bet there's a metaclass somewhere) removes anything it doesn't see as a bona instance-level pydantic field.  So I had to put `server_list` outside of the class.

```
from datetime import datetime
from typing import List, Optional, Any
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.schema import schema



class Share(BaseModel):
    exportstring: str
    mountpoint: str
    options: str


class Server(BaseModel):
    srvname: str
    shares: List[Share]

    #this doesn't worker.  The actual server class only gets declared
    #pydantics fields and pydantic utility methods/variables.
    #list : Any = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Server,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        server_list.append(self)

#have to declare standalone variable, or at least one outside
#of pydantic class definitions
server_list = []


srv1 = Server(srvname="horst1", shares=[Share(exportstring='export1server:/vol/asdfasdf', mountpoint='/opt/bla', options='nfsvers=4,rw,sync'), Share(exportstring='export1server:/vol/blub', mountpoint='/opt/bluba', options='nfsvers=4,rw,sync')])
srv2 = Server(srvname="harry", shares=[Share(exportstring='export1server:/vol/asdfasdf', mountpoint='/opt/bla', options='nfsvers=4,rw,sync'), Share(exportstring='export1server:/vol/blub', mountpoint='/opt/bluba', options='nfsvers=4,rw,sync')])

#hardcoded iteration
for srv in [srv1,srv2]:
    print(f"\n\n{srv=}")

# for srv2 in Server.list:

#registered by class 
for srv2 in server_list:
    print(f"\n\n{srv2=}")
```

#### output:

```
srv=Server(srvname='horst1', shares=[Share(exportstring='export1server:/vol/asdfasdf', mountpoint='/opt/bla', options='nfsvers=4,rw,sync'), Share(exportstring='export1server:/vol/blub', mountpoint='/opt/bluba', options='nfsvers=4,rw,sync')])


srv=Server(srvname='harry', shares=[Share(exportstring='export1server:/vol/asdfasdf', mountpoint='/opt/bla', options='nfsvers=4,rw,sync'), Share(exportstring='export1server:/vol/blub', mountpoint='/opt/bluba', options='nfsvers=4,rw,sync')])


srv2=Server(srvname='horst1', shares=[Share(exportstring='export1server:/vol/asdfasdf', mountpoint='/opt/bla', options='nfsvers=4,rw,sync'), Share(exportstring='export1server:/vol/blub', mountpoint='/opt/bluba', options='nfsvers=4,rw,sync')])


srv2=Server(srvname='harry', shares=[Share(exportstring='export1server:/vol/asdfasdf', mountpoint='/opt/bla', options='nfsvers=4,rw,sync'), Share(exportstring='export1server:/vol/blub', mountpoint='/opt/bluba', options='nfsvers=4,rw,sync')])
```